# validation for textbox setting dashes(-) automatically

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

i have this code m trying to validate it but unable to so what i want it to look like this `12-12345-1-1` when the user types in the text box it should be able to get the dashes automatically is this possible through *C#* or *j-query*

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtNum" runat="server" placeholder="number" class="form-control" OnTextChanged="txtNum_TextChanged1" ></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="regxNum" ValidationExpression="\d{3}\d{3}\d{4}" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Invalid Num#" ControlToValidate="txtNum" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

**C#**

```
if ((txtNum.Text.ToString().Length == 2) || (txtNum.Text.ToString().Length == 5) || (txtNum.Text.ToString().Length == 1))
      txtNum.Text = txtNum.Text.ToString() + "-";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a client side function to add a dash, you can do something like this.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" MaxLength="12"></asp:TextBox>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#<%= TextBox1.ClientID %>').keydown(function () {
        var txt = $(this).val();
        if (txt.length === 2 || txt.length === 8 || txt.length === 10) {
            $(this).val(txt += "-");
        }
    });
</script>
```

A c# example would be something like this

```
//source string
string input = "12-12-3451-1";

//remove wrong dashes first
input = input.Replace("-", "");

//loop all characters in the string, doing this in a loop prevents index out of range
//exception when string it shorter that 9
for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
{
    //insert the appropriate dashes
    if (i == 2 || i == 8 || i == 10)
    {
        input = input.Insert(i, "-");
    }
}

//show results
Label1.Text = input;
```